# find the applications/path in Redhat which uses java 1.6

Tags: linux, redhat

We use the server

> Linux version 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64 
>   (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)(GCC))

For some upgrade process, we need to find out all the current applications, which uses Java version 1.6. This is a bit hard to check one by one.

We use the below commands as of now

```
grep -rnw "/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/JRE_WA/" -e "1.6"
grep -rnw "/sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jdk/" -e "1.6"
```

But these commands are giving all the folders, which has `1.6`

Can someone help us to find exactly the applications/path where `1.6` Java version is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find better solution with this find command

```
find /opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/JRE_WA/ -name 'java' -executable -type f
find /sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jdk/ -name 'java' -executable -type f
```

or more 1.6

```
find /opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/JRE_WA/ -name 'java' -executable -type f|grep 6
find /sbcimp/run/tp/sun/jdk/ -name 'java' -executable -type f|grep 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, We will try this. and Thanks for you efforts to provide and answer.